# Cauchy Series and Fermat Last Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Ok, I am studying some analysis with "The Way of Analysis" by Strichartz and couldn't quite figure out what the author is trying to extract from this question.

Let $a_k, b_k, c_k, n_k$ for $k = 1,2...$
be an enumeration of all quadruples
of positive integers with $n_k > 2$. Let $x_j = 0 \ if \ a_k^{n_k} + b_k^{n_k} \neq c_k^{n_k} \ \forall  \ k \leq j $. Otherwise set $x_j = \frac{1}{k}$ where $k$ is the smallest integer such that $a_k^{n_k} + b_k^{n_k} = c_k^{n_k}$. Prove that $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$  is Cauchy. What is the relationship between the Axiom
of Archimedes for the real number given by this Cauchy sequence
and Fermat's Last Theorem?

Now I know Fermat Last Theorem was "recently" proved to be true, possibly after the book was published (I dont know). I dont I think I am able to get the point he is trying to make. The axiom says I can always find a number smaller than any real number. The sequence is Cauchy and hence converges. What I am tempted to say is that it will converge to $0$ even though we dont know if the fermat equation has any solutions, due to the way the $x_j$ was constructed. My reasoning: If there were solutions, no matter how many, the term if $1/k$ is getting eventually smaller and we can always strech out the sequence as long as we want to get it inside any neighborhood to satisfy the limit property. I cant quite make the link between the axiom of archimedes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLT is equivalent to $(x_j)$ being the zero sequence. If FLT were not true, I am not sure to understand the definition of $x_j$ for those $j$ such that there would exist some $k\leqslant j$ such that $a_k^{n_k}+b_k^{n_k}=c_k^{n_k}$ but, as is written, the sequence $(x_j)$ is not Cauchy. If one replaces, in this case, the definition $x_j=1/k$ by $x_j=1/j$, then $(x_j)$ is Cauchy even if FLT were not true.